# Are there public transport data for Germany freely available?

Tags: data-request, germany, public-transport

I wonder if there are some up-to-date web sites with data for S-bahn, U-bahn and other means of traffics in German cities. I found some before but not sure if they are updated regularly. Later I will add some links for those but others are welcomed to do so as well.

p.s. My main interest in Baden-Würtemberg / Stuttgart area but others are welcome to contribute will available infos...

Comment: It's not open data but someone collected API endpoints for a list of public transport data [here](https://gist.github.com/derhuerst/2b7ed83bfa5f115125a5).

Answer (score 7):

Again, OpenStreetMap to the rescue: it has a whole tag scheme related to public transport services. Pointers:

- [ÖPNVKarte](http://openbusmap.org/) (German, real domain [öpnvkarte.de] contains an umlaut, openbusmap.org is just a proxy domain) has a nice rendered world map, showing airport, train stations, rails, buses, subways, trams, ... **worldwide** (with varying degrees of coverage, of course). The [corresponding page on OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/%C3%96pnvkarte) gives background information.
- More general, the article [Public transport on OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_transport) lists all important tags for extracting relevant data from a data dump.

Answer (score 5):

Some information on public transportation in Berlin

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Berlin/Transportation

Recently (Nov. 2015), the Deutsche Bahn AG released some data on its infrastructure:

http://data.deutschebahn.com/datasets/

Answer (score 1):

If you search for timetable Data, you can find a collection of Datasources here: https://github.com/highsource/verbundkarte
This list contains Links to downloadable timetable data (not APIs) from german transport companies. Also inofficial sources are listed.

You can also find worldwide GTFS datasets on https://transitfeeds.com/

If you only interested in the coordinates of the stops you can find a list of scripts to extract the stop-data on https://github.com/public-transport/european-transport-modules – including a script for [VVS](https://github.com/de-stops/vvs-stops)